# PHP: How to I get multiple variables go to one page?

Tags: php, html, css

I am trying to make a flash server for my classroom in high-school and I have all of my .swf files downloaded. I have a catalog page where all the games listed. I also have a page where I want to play the games on but I don't want to make a page for every single game. I was wondering how can I click on any game and it will go onto that single page?

Would setting variable and using sessions solve this problem? I have been asking my coding teacher but he doesn't know much about php.

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION["doom.swf"]= "doom";
$_SESSION["pong.swf"]= "pong";
?>
```

Would this work and would I have to echo the variable on the other page when it is clicked?

Comment: Seems like what you're looking for is the ability to create a page identified by a dynamic route paramter. Eg. `mypage.com/game/doom` and `mypage.com/game/pong` where the last bit is variable like so: `mypage.com/game/{nameOfYourGame}`. Am I right?

Comment: I really don't understand what you are trying to ask. Do you want to link to the *same* page for each game but loading a different game on said page, or are you trying to link to different pages for each game like Emil commented? Also we need your code in order to help you, we do not write the code for you.

Comment: link to the same page for each game but loading a different game on said page. I am trying to write up some code but with no result yet nothing seems to be working I don't need the code written for me I just need to know what i need to use and research to figure it out. Thank you!

Comment: friendly url work if you setup .htaccess next to index.php, and every request redirected to index.php. Frameworks uses this technic

Answer (score 2):

I think you need `URL` queries like, `example.com/play.php?game=doom` or `example.com/play.php?game=pong`

```
<?php
    start_session();
    $game = $_GET['game'];

    if($game == "doom") {
        // Do something
    } else if($game == "pong") {
        // Do something
    } else {
       // Game Not Found
    }  
?>
```

Or you can use `switch` method instead of the `if` method.
This is a really simple way to do what would you like.